# GIT Extensions and a separate working directory

Tags: git, git-extensions

I am fairly new with using GIT and specifically GIT extensions. I am trying to get the correct version control method for my software application config files.

With GIT extensions, I create a remote repository (all good). I then clone this into my local repository (all good). Then then add gitignore etc (all good). When I finish making changes to my software application, it then compiles these changes into a compressed file and then removes (deletes) all the config files. And this unfortunately includes an local GIT repo.

I think what I need is 3 different things:

1. Remote repo
2. Local repo
3. Working directory

At the moment I have 2 and 3 as the same thing. I need these to be separated out. I want to know if there is a way of achieving this with GIT extensions?

Comment: Normal Git works the way you want it to. I find it hard to believe that an add-on *takes away* this useful functionality, but if it does, perhaps you should just stop using the add-on.

Comment: How is Git Extensions related to what you're doing?